Scheduled notifications, sometimes, don't show up in Android (Flutter)
I am implementing reminders where I schedule notifications using zonedSchedule method of flutter_local_notifications package. The problem is that the notifications don't show up sometimes.
What do you think might be causing to that?
When I want to display notification simultaneously they always show up.
As I said, scheduled notifications, also, show up sometimes.
I am using priorities and importances of Max.
My permissions are also okay.
I don't think that this is not caused by time-zone related issues.

Some android phones don't support scheduled background notifications, this is probably the reason that the notifications sometimes pop up and sometimes not. You will only get a notification if the app is not terminated on the devices that do not support this. There is no solution that i know or i could find to this

If this is the case, no notifications would be shown up. Isn't it?

I use it to schedule reminders works perfectly fine to me, here's my code config for the notification maybe you can try checking it once.
  _notificationPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    id,
    null,
    description,
    isTmzAffected
        ? tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledTime, tz.getLocation(currentTimeZone))
        : tz.TZDateTime.local(
            scheduledTime.year,
            scheduledTime.month,
            scheduledTime.day,
            scheduledTime.hour,
            scheduledTime.minute,
          ),
    NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        _androidReminderNotificationChannel.id +
            docType.name +
            (sound ?? ''),
        'channelId',
        channelDescription: _androidReminderNotificationChannel.description,
        importance: Importance.max,
        autoCancel: true,
        ongoing: pinReminder ?? false,
        actions: [],
        playSound: true,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(
          sound?.replaceAll('.mp3', ''),
        ),
      ),
      iOS: docType == DocumentType.todo
          ? DarwinNotificationDetails(
              sound: sound?.replaceAll('.mp3', '.caf'),
              presentSound: true,
            )
          : DarwinNotificationDetails(
              sound: sound?.replaceAll('.mp3', '.caf'),
              presentSound: true,
            ),
    ),
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.alarmClock,
    payload: payloadJson,
  );

Note : make sure you have added valid permissions for alarm

I partially solved the problem by simply changing nothing acutally. The test device is low-end, I think the problem is caused by how the device is handling notifications.
